# start-job loop how to call second script

Tags: powershell

Can anyone please suggest me what is wrong - I am calling second script from first so that 
I can run the compare in background or parallel, due to bug in IDM software I need to 
execute loop two times.

I need to call 5 scripts from my main script ( frist script) so that all five scripts run 
parallelly.

First Script -

==================================================
Error message

Attribute cannot be added because it would cause the variable sbtFile with value C to become invalid.
    + CategoryInfo          : MetadataError: (:) [Start-Job], ValidationMetadataException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ValidateSetFailure,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartJobCommand

The command cannot find the job because the CompareCtrlMasterCtrlModelESS name was not found. Verify the value of the Name parameter, and then try the comman
d again.
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (CompareCtrlMasterCtrlModelESS:String) [Wait-Job], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : JobWithSpecifiedNameNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WaitJobCommand

The command cannot find the job because the CompareCtrlMasterCtrlModelESS name was not found. Verify the value of the Name parameter, and then try the comman
d again.
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (CompareCtrlMasterCtrlModelESS:String) [Receive-Job], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : JobWithSpecifiedNameNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ReceiveJobCommand

Regards
Naveen

Comment: If for every job you start, you immediately call `Wait-Job`, `Receive-Job` for it, nothing is happening in parallel.  You might as well skip using jobs entirely.  The benefit only occurs if you kick off multiple jobs at once, then `Wait-Job` for all of them.

Answer (score 2):

You run `Start-Job -Name "CompareCtrlMasterCtrlModelESS"` in a loop, so you try to create multiple jobs with the same name. Try `Start-Job -Name "CompareCtrlMasterCtrlModelESS$i"` (with ordinal suffix).

Comment: Giving error message - The command cannot find the job because the CompareCtrlMasterCtrlModelESS1 name was not found. Verify the value of the Name parameter, and then try the comma
nd again

Comment: Assign `"CompareCtrlMasterCtrlModelESS$i"` to a variable inside the loop like $jobName and then use that variable for Start-Job, Wait-Job and Receive-Job inside the loop.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dmitry & Keith, I understood now and implemented.